# How to implement scrollview on 1 XML file for all "normal" device sizes?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I have a scrollView in my XML file. I'd like to use "match_parent" for layout Height but I also want to place a button on top of scrollview so that button doesn't scroll. However, I can't seem to do this without the button disappearing on smaller phones like Nexus ONE. The only way I can is if I use a specific layout_Height like the 450dp I currently have. But with 450dp layout height you can see that it looks great on Nexus ONE size but on bigger device sizes like Nexus 6, it's too small.

How can I make all device sizes in "Normal" layout have a scrollview look like the Nexus ONE where only a little space is left for a button?

Here's what I have with layout_height="450dp" :

[image]

Nexus 6:

[image]

Both devices in same XML file:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/memories"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Memories >"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="#808000"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SavedBroadcasts"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" >

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do your XML code like following way that I have mentioned, It's working properly in my app.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/memories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Memories"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/memories"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="#808000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SavedBroadcasts"
            android:layout_width="304dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And you will be get same layout visible on all the devices.

*Nexus One*
[image: Your layout look like in Nexus One]

*Nexus 6*
[image: In Nexus 6]

*Pixel 2*
[image: In Pixel 2]